# How to place i3bar on top?

Tags: linux, i3-window-manager

How can I set i3bar of i3 window manager on top of the screen rather than being placed on its default position, that is bottom.

I tried to examine the ~/.config/i3/config file but couldn't work it out by myself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add `position top`

```
bar {
        position top
[original contents of "bar" goes here]
}
```

After adding this, you will need to refresh which is mod (windows key) + shift + r (unless you have changed it from the default).

Comment: It doesn't work. I added it into `config` file, it doubled the bar, then I found and added it inside the already existing `bar{}` it didn't change anything. And I **r**estarted `i3` as well. Should I create and add it to another, say `i3status` or `i3bar` file, and what is the meaning of the open `<snip>` tag? I want to know where am I being wrong?

Comment: I removed the misadded `:` and it worked. I'm blaming [tag:CSS] for it :P But my questions are still in power, that is if I could add it into a separate `i3bar` file, and the meaning of unclosing `<snip>` tag.

Comment: The snip is just something to show where I deleted out my own config for this post as its not related to the `position` variable.

Comment: In addition to answer, related part of the official doc: https://i3wm.org/docs/4.12/userguide.html#i3bar_position

Comment: Mod + Shift + C (read config file) is enough, no need to restart